# Regex condition after and before a known phrase

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to capture a phrase that starts with a Capital letter between 2 known phrase. Let's say between "Known phrase, " and the word "The".

For example in the text below, the phrase I'm trying to capture is: `Stuff TO CApture That always start with Capital letter but stop capturing when`

> Ignore Words Known phrase, ignore random phrase Stuff TO CApture That always start with Capital letter but stop capturing when The appears.

Regex I have tried: `(?<=Known phrase, ).*(?= The)` and `Known phrase, (.*) The`
These regex also captures `ignore random phrase`. How do I ignore this?

Comment: Try it like this with a capturing group and a non greedy quantifier `Known phrase, [a-z ]+([A-Z].*?) The` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/sYRJDB/1)

Comment: @Thefourthbird it works! Thanks! Did not think of matching lowercases and spaces after the known phrase.

Comment: Glad it works. I have added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your exaple data, you might use:

`Known phrase, [a-z ]+([A-Z].*?) The`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sYRJDB/1)

**Explanation**

- `Known phrase,` Match literally
- `[a-z ]+` Match 1+ times a lowercase character or a space (Add to the character class what you would allow to match except an Uppercase character)
- `([A-Z].*?)` Capture in a group matching an uppercase character followed by 0+ times any character except a newline.
- `The` Match literally

Answer (score 2):

I guess as regular expression is left side greedy you should first try to match anything that is not capital letters

Something like `/Start[^A-Z]*(.*)stop/`
(`[^A-Z]` matches anything that is not capital letter)

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/df4sOX/1)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of what you are trying to do, but, trying to stick with your code, `(?<=Known phrase, )([^A-Z]*)(.*)(?=The)` should do the trick: the text you need is in the group 2. 
If you need to match everything just change to `(.*)(?<=Known phrase, )([^A-Z]*)(.*)(?=The)(.*)` and get your text in group 3.